# OAuthException "(#210) Subject must be a page."

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-oauth

I Keep getting OAuthException `(#210) Subject must be a page.` error even if I am using the Page Access Token **and not the App Access Token**.

I am using the following:

1. Latest JavaScript SDK from facebook [(//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js))
2. Calling the `/{PAGE_ID}/tabs?app_id={APP_ID}&method=POST&access_token={PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}` using the FB.api method once the user is logged in.

My Application is **not FBML** but a Canvas / iFrame App. What am i doing wrong?

I have researched the web including the Stackoverflow and other facebook forums but still no answer on this. OAuth is Enabled for my Application.

Also, If i copy and paste the link in Browser it works fine. It does not if I do it using the API.

Answer (score 5):

I finally got it working.

However, Instead of using the FB.api to call the link above, i used jQuery.

I used jQuery "$.getJson(url)" and it worked.

It works as below.

Construct the link as below.

"https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/tabs?app_id={APP_ID}&method=POST&access_token={PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}&callback=?"

Call the jQuery method as below.
"$.getJSON(pageUrl, OnCallBack);" where "OnCallBack" is the call back method. You can do anything that you would need in the call back. In my case it was something like below.

```
    function OnCallBack(r, s) {

        var html = "";
        if (s == "success" && !r.error) {
            for (p in r) {
                html += p + ": " + r[p] + "<br />";
            }
        } else {
            html = r.error.message;
        }
        $("#dv").html(html);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To anybody who gets this error again:
I have get the same error message  while I use wininet to post a  https request to https://graph.facebook.com/......

I just changed the verb from "POST" to "GET" , and then it works well:

```
//string strVerb = "POST";
string strVerb = "GET";
```

PS: variable "strVerb" is used as the 2nd parameter of windows function HttpOpenRequest.