# Renaming a facebook page tab

Tags: facebook-page

I have created a facebook application to add a page tab in any facebook page.
for this i have a pagetab name in facebook integration of application's setting part.
Suppose i have added the name as "MyFbTab"

Now the problem is when someone add my application to his page then a tab will be added with name MyFbTab , but i want to ask user for a name and then the tab created with the name entered .

I am using facebook js sdk for this 
So please help regarding to fb js sdk

I have found a method for this in php sdk but want to do this in js sdk

regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use the API to change the name given to an installed page tab, see here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Short version, make a POST request to
`/PAGE_ID/tabs/APP_ID?custom_name=MyPageTabName&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN`

{edit}

In the Javascript SDK you won't be able to do this directly because the Javascrtipt SDK will be using the user's access token and you'll need to make that call with the page access token you retrieved from the user's `/accounts` connection earlier.

[OAuthException "(#210) Subject must be a page."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396384/oauthexception-210-subject-must-be-a-page) has an example of someone using Jquery to take the page access token and make the API call that way. In their case they're using it to install a tab rather than edit an existing one, but it's almost exactly the same for your problem

Comment: can you please suggest how to make this post request using js sdk :)

Comment: This works for me, i just need to change /{APP_ID}? for /app_{APP_ID}?

Hope this helps